# How do I select count() and LIMIT?

Tags: mysql, database, select

```
SELECT * FROM ...LIMIT 5, 10
```

But what if I want the total rows? I don't want to make another query without the limit. I just want this one query to return the total rows if I didn't put the LIMIT in there.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with running multiple queries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the only way is like this (use 2 queries):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ..... FROM table WHERE ...  LIMIT 5, 10;
```

and right after run this :

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

read more :

http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/mysql-get-total-number-of-rows-when-using-limit.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
select count (*) from table_name
```